# sync db between prod and dev system

Tags: python, django, postgresql, synchronization

I need a tool to sync postgreSQL database between a production system and a local development system.

Data needs to be fetched from the production server to the local development server.

Example: I want to fetch all rows of the model TicketType (about 100 rows), but not all rows of the model Ticket (several thousands).

I know how to use pg_dump and I know how I can use dumpdata in django.

But maybe there is a better solution.

(I don't need a solution to get changes from dev to prod, that's managed with south.)

Comment: whats wrong with dumping your table using postgres tools and loading it using postgres? Does django need to be involved at all in the dumping/loading process?

Comment: You could also consider specifying different databases in django and write a script which copies the desired models/tables... (will be less performant for bigger dbs) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any recent version of Postgresql, you can use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), or if you are using Postgres 9.3, you can use the nifty new [postgres_fdw](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html). You could also test out the postgres_fdw extension backported for 9.2 at https://github.com/commandprompt/postgres_fdw